# Semântica - Esconder ou remover mensagens de feedback?

Tags: html, jquery, css

sei que essa pergunta pode ser fechada por ser baseada em opiniões mas, por intuito de manter boas práticas, segue o cenário a seguir:

1- Usuário realizou um cadastro no site.

2- Exibo uma mensagem de feedback e após 5 segundos escondo o elemento da mensagem.

A dúvida é, o certo seria remover o elemento e inserir apenas quando for necessário ou deixá-lo na página e apenas fazer um toggle para mostrar e esconder?

Exemplo de como uso hoje em dia:

```
<span style="display:none"> Exemplo feedback </span>
```

**Reforçando**: O mais semântico seria esconder e mostrar o elemento usando `display` ou usar o `Jquery` para adicioná-lo e removê-lo?

Comment: Pensando semanticamente vc deveria destruir-lo, pois mesmo com display:none os leitores de tela vão encontra-lo, a não ser que vc use um aria-hidden="true" junto com o display:none. Eu tb deixaria o próprio usuário fechar a mensagem se fosse desejo dele, tipo colocando um X pra fechar o box ou algo assim... Mas ai já é questão de opinião mesmo...

Comment: Concordo com @hugocsl. Agora semanticamente falando, se você tem um "modal de avisos", você pode mantê-lo no html, desde que use sempre o mesmo, trocando apenas a mensagem que será exibida, para diferentes propósitos, se for uma "janela padrão". Agora se aparece apenas uma mensagem de feedback eventual, e as outras mensagens de aviso são diferentes (diferentes estilos de modal), é melhor remover o elemento. Mencionei modal só para deixar mais claro, pode simplesmente ser um `span` posicionado no por exemplo